# In Microsoft Excel, how do I copy a range of ROWS from sheet1 into a range (of equal size) of COLUMNS on sheet2?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How do I copy a RANGE of rows from sheet1 into a RANGE (of equal size) of columns on sheet2 ?

Everything I see allows one to hold either the row or column with an absolute $ sign before the rowColumn ... but nothing I can find allows one to transpose the relative drag across column to increase the row number ...

Is this possible?

Comment: Copy the rows; then select the first cell in the destination sheet: Paste Special / Transpose

Comment: Thanks Ron,  This does work.   I was hoping for being able to drag in the future to modify the range if I add to (extend) the source range in the future ... and also have the destination field "update" if I make changes to the source range ... but this does work for immediate use.   Thanks again,

Comment: You can use formulas, perhaps.  I'll post an answer

Answer (score 1):

For Copying: Copy the rows; then select the first cell in the destination sheet: Paste Special / Transpose

However, if you want to use formulas, you can try the following with your data starting in Sheet1!A1, put the following formula where you want to start the transposition; and fill down and to the right.  Adjust `Sheet1!$A$1:$F$10` to reflect the largest possible range you might use.

```
=IF(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$F$10,COLUMNS($A:A),ROWS($1:1))="","",INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$F$10,COLUMNS($A:A),ROWS($1:1)))
```

Comment: PERFECT !!!   This is EXACTLY what I needed!!!  You're the man, Ron ...    On sheet1, I moved my data over to start perfectly at A1 and then copied your formula into sheet2 where I wanted to start.  I then expanded the formula to the right across the ROW and it copied from the COLUMNS on sheet1 into that ROW on sheet2.  This is exactly what I wanted.  Now, I will study this for a bit and see if I can figure out how it is working.  LOL.

Comment: @RichWalt The "trick" is how the arguments used for `row` and `column` in the `INDEX` function increment as the function is dragged right and/or down.   And your data table can start anyplace -- you just have to change the range of the `array` argument.

Comment: @RichWalt IF you could mark my response as the answer, I would appreciate it.